# git gui using diff -b as difftool

Tags: git, user-interface, diff

I'm looking for a way to keep using git gui to commit changes as I always do, but get rid of indentation changes (as i'm not the only dev). using the '-b' switch to diff does the trick but i'm looking for the right place to tell this to git gui ...
Any solution will be appriciated!

Comment: Another solution would be to tell git to consider whitespace changes as no changes at all to avoid indentation commits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused by your question.  '-b' doesn't get rid of indentation changes.  It just hides them when it shows you the diff.

You probably should handle the tabs vs spaces issue in your editor.

Comment: Yes I already noticed it, so the question could then be "is there a way to tell git not to consider whitespace and tab changes as commitable changes" but now i'm wondering if that's really what i want :)

Answer (score 0):

[This patch](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-git-gui-add-config-value-gui-diffopts-for-passing-additional-diff-options-td5947265.html) seems to do what you wish.